# Enviar imagem que está no servidor como anexo de email

Tags: php, codeigniter, phpmailer

Preciso enviar um email com folder's (imagens) que já estão no servidor.
Alguém tem uma ideia de como fazer isso?
O envio do email já está funcionando.
Estou utilizando codeigniter e phpmailer.

Comment: Você pode setar o PHPMailer para HTML, e então, você envia o link para as imagens em uma tag <img> ou, se não quiser exibir a imagem, você coloca o link em uma tag <a> e seta o atributo download, ficando assim: <a href="suaimagem" download > Baixar Imagem </a>

Comment: Você quer que a imagem seja adicionada ao corpo do e-mail ou como anexo ao mesmo?

Answer (score 2):

Há algumas formas.

A primeira é ter a imagem uma caminho público do servidor e apenas utilizar a tag:

```
<img src="caminho/absoluto/imagem.png" />
```

Também há a possibilidade de adicionar a imagem com o próprio PHPMailer usando o método **AddEmbeddedImage**

http://phpmailer.github.io/PHPMailer/classes/PHPMailer.PHPMailer.PHPMailer.html#method_addEmbeddedImage

```
$mail->AddEmbeddedImage('img/error.png', 'teste');
```

Se eu não me engano você precisa colocar uma tag com o id da imagem anexada:

```
<img src='cid:teste'>
```

Abs

Answer (score 1):

**Resolvido**, adicionei essa linha:

```
$mail->AddAttachment("caminho_da_imagem/imagem.png");
```